# Existence of symmetric trembling hand perfect equilibria

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Consider symmetric and finite game. By Nash (1950), the game must have at least one symmetric equilibrium ([proof](https://ink.library.smu.edu.sg/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=2212&context=sis_research)). Also, it must have at least one trembling hand perfect equilibrium ([proof](http://www.princeton.edu/~fgul/2000handouts/H3.1.pdf)).

> Question: must it have at least one **symmetric** trembling hand perfect equilibrium?

My thoughts on this:

- We demonstrate the existence of a trembling hand perfect equilibrium by looking at a sequence of perturbed games which converge to the original game.
- By Nash (1950), each perturbed game has a symmetric equilibrium.
- Therefore (?), the original game has a symmetric trembling hand perfect equilibrium.